# Missing Android 3.1 SDK in Visual Studio 2013 using Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

So I just reinstalled the lastest version of Xamarin after a clean install of my laptop.  There were no errors during the Xamarin install, so everything seemed okay.  However, I went to open an existing project based on Android 3.1 (API 12) and got the following error when I compiled:

Unsupported or invalid $(TargetFrameworkVersion) value of 'v3.1'. Please update your Project Options.

Checked out my project properties and found that both the Compile and Target Android version combos were blank.  I have several versions listed in the combos, but v3.1 (API 12) is nowhere to be found.  When I look in the Android SDK Manager, it shows that Android 3.1 (API 12) is installed.  Anyone know why it would be missing in Visual Studio/Xamarin?

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We removed some of the API levels. Your application can still run on these completely fine, but you can't use them to Compile against or to Target. You will want to set your Target Framework the latest version API 21 currently and set the Minimum to the minimum you want. I usually recommend Target = 21, Minimum either 15 or 10 based on AppCompat that you need.

http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1/#Removal_of_API_Levels